# Avoid multiple jumping

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Just playing with SpriteKit and Swift, I'm making a little cube jumping.

I can't understand how to do it but I want to avoid multiple jumping on touch: if I touch the screen while the cube is flying it will jump again further...

I make the player jumping on `touchesBegan`

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    player.jump(Float(self.timeSinceLast))
}
```

The method `jump()` is

```
func jump(timeSinceLast: Float) {
    self.sprite.physicsBody.applyImpulse(CGVector(0, self.jumpingForce * timeSinceLast))
}
```

I tried to set a boolean `isJumping` before the call in `touchesBegan()` and check for it in `jump()` but with no sucess...

```
func jump(timeSinceLast: Float) {

    if !self.isJumping {
        self.isJumping = true;
        self.sprite.physicsBody.applyImpulse(CGVector(0, self.jumpingForce * timeSinceLast))
        self.isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code? Thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to figure out how to detect that your player is in contact with the ground.  When you are done applying the impulse to the character, it still has to travel up and then back down.  This takes time, much longer than the time it takes to apply the impulse.

If your ground is flat, you could do something as simple as checking the y-value of your character's position to determine if it is appropriate to apply the impulse.

If your ground has a more complex shape, then you'll want to detect if there is a collision between your player and the ground object before applying the impulse.